# Rotation Matrix given angle and point in X,Y,Z

Tags: c#, math, matrix

I am doing image manipulation and I want to rotate all of the pixels in xyz space based on an angle, the origin, and an x,y, and z coordinate.

I just need to setup the proper matrix (4x4) and then I will be good from there.  The Angle is in degrees, not radians and the x,y,z are all going to be from -1 to 1 (floats)

EDIT:

Ok, here is the code that I whipped up to do the rotation about a given line defined by the origin and an X, Y, Z coorinate.

```
        float ang = angD * (float)(Math.PI / 180);  // from degrees to radians, if needed
        //U = n*n(t) + cos(a)*(I-n*n(t)) + sin(a)*N(x).

        var u = MatrixDouble.Identity(4);  // 4x4 Identity Matrix
        u = u.Multiply(Math.Cos(ang));

        var n = new MatrixDouble(1, 4, new List<double> { x, y, z, 0 });
        var nt = n.Transpose();

        // This next part is the N(x) matrix.  The data is inputted in Column
        // first order and fills in the 4x4 matrix with the given 16 Doubles
        var nx = new MatrixDouble(4, 4, new List<double> { 0, z, -y, 0, -z, 0, x, 0, y, -x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 });

        nx = nx.Multiply(Math.Sin(ang));

        var ret = nt.Multiply(n);
        ret[3, 3] = 1;

        u = u.Subtract(ret);

        u = ret.Add(u.Add(nx));
```

It's a little complicated and I'm using a custom Matrix library, but nothing up there should be too hard to implement with any functioning Matrix lib.

Phew, lots of math!

Comment: I'm guessing you want the point defined by the "x, y and z coordinate" to remain invariant. How are you representing a point in xyz space as a 4-vector?

Comment: I'm not representing the points as a 4x4 vector.  The transformation matrix is the 4x4 and the point is a 4x1.  Multiplying them together gets me my p' which is the pixel only rotated.  I'll update my post with the code that I made.

Comment: A "4x4 vector"? You are not being careful with terminology.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb.  4x4 Matrix :)  lol, at least I didn't say Matrice!!! heehee

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The complete rotation matrices are derived and given at https://sites.google.com/site/glennmurray/glenn-murray-ph-d/rotation-matrices-and-formulas/rotation-about-an-arbitrary-axis-in-3-dimensions.

From the paper:

5.2 The simplified matrix for rotations about the origin

Note this assumes that (u, v, w) is a direction vector for the axis of rotation and that u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 1.

[image: Simplified 3D matrix for rotations about the origin.]

If you have a point (x, y, z) that you want to rotate, then we can obtain a function of of seven variables that yields the rotated point:

*f*(x, y, z, u, v, w, theta) =

[image: Formula for rotated point.]

The paper also includes matrices and formulas for rotations about an arbitrary axis (not necessarily through the origin), Java code available under the Apache license, and a link to a web app that illustrates rotations.

Comment: Thou the math was a bit much to digest, this did end up working.  It took me a bit, but I got it working and it is a general case.  Thank you!

Comment: hello Glenn, i know this is so old answer but the link which is given by you is dead. If possible can you make an update?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Matrix3D Structure ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.matrix3d.aspx)) - Represents a 4 x 4 matrix used for transformations in 3-D space

Take a look here for a tutorial: [Building a 3D Engine](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/building-a-simple-3d-engine-with-silverlight/)

Essentially, matrices are built for X, Y, and Z rotations and then you can multiply the rotations in any order.

```
public static Matrix3D NewRotateAroundX(double radians)
{
    var matrix = new Matrix3D();
    matrix._matrix[1, 1] = Math.Cos(radians);
    matrix._matrix[1, 2] = Math.Sin(radians);
    matrix._matrix[2, 1] = -(Math.Sin(radians));
    matrix._matrix[2, 2] = Math.Cos(radians);
    return matrix;
}
public static Matrix3D NewRotateAroundY(double radians)
{
    var matrix = new Matrix3D();
    matrix._matrix[0, 0] = Math.Cos(radians);
    matrix._matrix[0, 2] = -(Math.Sin(radians));
    matrix._matrix[2, 0] = Math.Sin(radians);
    matrix._matrix[2, 2] = Math.Cos(radians);
    return matrix;
}
public static Matrix3D NewRotateAroundZ(double radians)
{
    var matrix = new Matrix3D();
    matrix._matrix[0, 0] = Math.Cos(radians);
    matrix._matrix[0, 1] = Math.Sin(radians);
    matrix._matrix[1, 0] = -(Math.Sin(radians));
    matrix._matrix[1, 1] = Math.Cos(radians);
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: While it is true that you can multiply the matrices in any order, you will not necessarily get the same answer if you do so.  Matrix multiplication is not commutative.  I give an example of products of rotation matrices about the axes giving different answers for different orders of multiplication in the paper linked at in my answer.

Comment: While it is true that MatrixX * MatrixY does not necessarily equal MatrixY * MatrixX, it is up to the OP to decide the order of multiplication.

Comment: You're confusing 2 different Matrix3D's.  Even though you reference the MSDN, that Matrix 3D doesn't have a "_matrix" member.

Answer (score 1):

Function `rotateAroundAxis()` rotates point around any axis in 3D. It is my solution to the rotation in 3D using analytic geometry and programming to model the process. The code is in JavaScript.

```
function rotateAroundAxis(A, B, C, alpha, precision) {
  // A is rotated point, BC is axis, alpha is angle
  // A, B, C are points in format [Ax, Ay, Az], alpha is float, precision is int
  // A2 is output in format [A2x, A2y, A2z]
  if((A[0] - B[0])*(A[1] - C[1]) == (A[1] - B[1])*(A[0] - C[0]) && (A[1] - B[1])*(A[2] - C[2]) == (A[1] - C[1])*(A[2] - B[2]) && (A[0] - B[0])*(A[2] - C[2]) == (A[0] - C[0])*(A[2] - B[2])) {
    return A
  }// Return the original point if it is on the axis.
  var D = findClosestPoint(A, B, C, precision);
  var w = crossProduct(new Array(C[0] - B[0], C[1] - B[1], C[2] - B[2]), new Array(C[0] - A[0], C[1] - A[1], C[2] - A[2]));
  var W = pointPlusVector(A, w);
  var sizeAW = vectorSize(A, W);
  var sizeDA = vectorSize(D, A);
  var sizeAE = sizeDA*(Math.sin(0.5*alpha))/(Math.cos(0.5*alpha));
  var E = new Array(A[0] + (W[0] - A[0])*sizeAE/sizeAW, A[1] + (W[1] - A[1])*sizeAE/sizeAW, A[2] + (W[2] - A[2])*sizeAE/sizeAW);
  var sizeDE = vectorSize(D, E);
  var sizeEF = sizeAE*Math.sin(alpha/2);
  var F = new Array(D[0] + (E[0] - D[0])*(sizeDE - sizeEF)/sizeDE, D[1] + (E[1] - D[1])*(sizeDE - sizeEF)/sizeDE, D[2] + (E[2] - D[2])*(sizeDE - sizeEF)/sizeDE);
  var A2 = new Array(A[0] + 2*(F[0] - A[0]), A[1] + 2*(F[1] - A[1]), A[2] + 2*(F[2] - A[2]))
  return A2;
}

function angleSize(A, S, B) {
  ux = A[0] - S[0]; uy = A[1] - S[1]; uz = A[2] - S[2];
  vx = B[0] - S[0]; vy = B[1] - S[1]; vz = B[2] - S[2];
  if((Math.sqrt(ux*ux + uy*uy + uz*uz)*Math.sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy + vz*vz)) == 0) {return 0}
  return Math.acos((ux*vx + uy*vy + uz*vz)/(Math.sqrt(ux*ux + uy*uy + uz*uz)*Math.sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy + vz*vz)));
}

function findClosestPoint(N, B, C, precision) {
  // We will devide the segment BC into many tiny segments and we will choose the point F where the |NB F| distance is the shortest.
  if(B[0] == C[0] && B[1] == C[1] && B[2] == C[2]) {return B}
  var shortest = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i <= precision; i++) {
    var Fx = Math.round(precision*precision*(B[0] + (C[0] - B[0])*i/precision))/(precision*precision);
    var Fy = Math.round(precision*precision*(B[1] + (C[1] - B[1])*i/precision))/(precision*precision);
    var Fz = Math.round(precision*precision*(B[2] + (C[2] - B[2])*i/precision))/(precision*precision);
    var sizeF = vectorSize(new Array(N[0], N[1], N[2]), new Array(Fx, Fy, Fz));
    if(i == 0 || sizeF < shortest) { // first run or condition
      shortest = sizeF;
      F = new Array(Fx, Fy, Fz);
    }
  }
  // recursion, if it is an outer point return findClosestPoint(we mirror further point in the closer one)
  if(F[0] == Math.round(precision*precision*(B[0]))/(precision*precision) && F[1] == Math.round(precision*precision*(B[1]))/(precision*precision) && F[2] == Math.round(precision*precision*(B[2]))/(precision*precision)) { // F == B
    if(Math.round(precision*precision*180*angleSize(C, B, N)/Math.PI)/(precision*precision) <= 90){return F} else {return findClosestPoint(N, new Array(2*B[0] - C[0], 2*B[1] - C[1], 2*B[2] - C[2]), B, precision)}
  } else if (F[0] == Math.round(precision*precision*(C[0]))/(precision*precision) && F[1] == Math.round(precision*precision*(C[1]))/(precision*precision) && F[2] == Math.round(precision*precision*(C[2]))/(precision*precision)) { // F == C
    if(Math.round(precision*precision*180*angleSize(B, C, N)/Math.PI)/(precision*precision) <= 90) {return F} else {return findClosestPoint(N, C, new Array(2*C[0] - B[0], 2*C[1] - B[1], 2*C[2] - B[2]), precision)}
  } else {return F;}
}

function vectorSize(A, B) {
  var ux = A[0] - B[0];
  var uy = A[1] - B[1];
  var uz = A[2] - B[2];
  return Math.sqrt(ux*ux + uy*uy + uz*uz);
}

function crossProduct(u, v) {
  return (new Array(u[1]*v[2] - u[2]*v[1], u[2]*v[0] - u[0]*v[2], u[0]*v[1] - u[1]*v[0]));
}

function pointPlusVector (A, v) {
  return (new Array(A[0] + v[0], A[1] + v[1], A[2] + v[2]));
}
```