# How do I rotate in object space in 3D (using Matrixes)

Tags: matrix, 3d, rotation, point

what I am trying to do is to set up functions that can perform global and object space rotations, but am having problems understand how to go about object space rotations, as just multiplying a point by the rotation only works for global space, so my idea was to build the rotation in object space, then multiply it by the inverse of the objects matrix, supposedly taking away all the excess rotation between object and global space, so still maintaining the object space rotation, but in global values, I was wrong in this logic, as it did not work, here is my code, if you want to inspect it, all functions it calls have been tested to work:

```
// build object space rotation
sf::Vector3<float> XMatrix (MultiplyByMatrix(sf::Vector3<float> (cosz,sinz,0)));
sf::Vector3<float> YMatrix (MultiplyByMatrix(sf::Vector3<float> (-sinz,cosz,0)));
sf::Vector3<float> ZMatrix (MultiplyByMatrix(sf::Vector3<float> (0,0,1)));

// build cofactor matrix
sf::Vector3<float> InverseMatrix[3];
CoFactor(InverseMatrix);

// multiply by the transpose of the cofactor matrix(the adjoint), to bring the rotation to world space coordinates
sf::Vector3<float> RelativeXMatrix = MultiplyByTranspose(XMatrix, InverseMatrix[0], InverseMatrix[1], InverseMatrix[2]);
sf::Vector3<float> RelativeYMatrix = MultiplyByTranspose(YMatrix, InverseMatrix[0], InverseMatrix[1], InverseMatrix[2]);
sf::Vector3<float> RelativeZMatrix = MultiplyByTranspose(ZMatrix, InverseMatrix[0], InverseMatrix[1], InverseMatrix[2]);

// perform the rotation from world space
PointsPlusMatrix(RelativeXMatrix, RelativeYMatrix, RelativeZMatrix);
```

Comment: Do you want to rotate object around arbitrary axis or one of the coordinate axes?

Comment: The answer to the general 3D problem is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188876/rotation-matrix-given-angle-and-point-in-x-y-z/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between rotation in world-space and object-space is where you apply the rotation matrix.

The usual way computer graphics uses matrices is to map vertex points:

- from object-space, (multiply by `MODEL` matrix to transform)
- into world-space, (then multiply by `VIEW` matrix to transform)
- into camera-space, (then multiply by `PROJECTION` matrix to transform)
- into projection-, or "clip"- space

Specifically, suppose points are represented as column vectors; then, you transform a point by left-multiplying it by a transformation matrix:

```
world_point = MODEL * model_point
camera_point = VIEW * world_point = (VIEW*MODEL) * model_point
clip_point = PROJECTION * camera_point = (PROJECTION*VIEW*MODEL) * model_point
```

Each of these transformation matrices may itself be the result of multiple matrices multiplied in sequence.  In particular, the `MODEL` matrix is often composed of a sequence of rotations, translations, and scalings, based on a hierarchical articulated model, e.g.:

```
MODEL = STAGE_2_WORLD * BODY_2_STAGE *
  SHOULDER_2_BODY * UPPERARM_2_SHOULDER *
  FOREARM_2_UPPERARM * HAND_2_FOREARM
```

So, whether you are rotating in model-space or world-space depends on which side of the `MODEL` matrix you apply your rotation matrix.  Of course, you can easily do both:

```
MODEL = WORLD_ROTATION * OLD_MODEL * OBJECT_ROTATION
```

In this case, `WORLD_ROTATION` rotates about the center of world-space, while `OBJECT_ROTATION` rotates about the center of object-space.

Comment: my problem is I need to maintain my object rotation, while still transfering it to world space, to imagine what I'm talking about, think of a vector in object space, rotated in object space, about a specific direction, I need the specific direction maintained, but also rotated into world space, if I'm making it somewhat clear, or are you saying to multiply my rotation matrix into object space, and just multiply it back into world space? does that work? sorry if the way I'm working this about sounds a little silly, I'm still somewhat new to matrix math. could you write a small example? thanks

Comment: Do you want to keep your object oriented in the same direction in worldspace, regardless of whatever articulation determines its location?  If so, you can just find this base location in worldspace (by transforming a single vertex with an existing `OLD_MODEL` matrix), and create an entirely new `MODEL` matrix which is just a translation to that point.

Comment: no, I need to find a way to keep the direction of the rotation the same, while taking the rotation matrix into world space, as the actual rotation of the points has to be done in world space :/, unless you know of a way to do the rotation in object space

Comment: Doing the rotation in object space is easy:  as my answer says, multiply the rotation matrix on the object-space side of the `MODEL` matrix.  What do you mean by "keep the direction of the rotation the same"?  The same as what?  The same relative to what?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the direction of the *axis* of your rotation to remain constant in worldspace, regardless of whatever articulation determines its location?

Comment: no, I already do transfer the rotation matrix into object space, but the rotation has to be applied to the mesh in world space, that is the problem, because since it has to be applied in world space, I have to find a way to transer the rotation to world space, but still keep the direction of the rotation it had in object space. sorry if I'm being a little unclear, the words to use are hard to find :(

Comment: Actually, maybe the problem is that you are using 3x3 matrices and 3-vectors, instead of 4x4 matrices and homogeneous coordinates.  I apologize for not looking closely at your code -- all my above advice applies to standard computer graphics transformations, in which a 4x4 matrix can represent rotations, translations, or any combination of them.  If you are not familiar with this method, look it up -- it will make your task much simpler!

Comment: there is no need of a 4x4 matrix, as I do my own position handeling, and there will be no need of skew, but what you said earlier about object rotation, are you saying I should do (RotationMatrix*model) and not (model*RotationMatrix) as is normally done for inertial rotation? or am I still misunderstanding. could you write a small sample of code that I could look at, and see what you mean, and apply to my circumstances, as it would be most helpful :)

Comment: The code sample in your question provides no information on what your matrix conventions are, so I cannot tell how to write code which will be compatible with yours.  The existing sample code in my question assumes the conventions that multiplication has been overloaded to perform matrix multiplication, that points are represented by column vectors, and that (as is usual with computer graphics) they are being mapped from object space into clip/camera space.  It should also work correctly for 3x3 rotation matrices which use those conventions.

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you mean by "inertial rotation", but I would tentatively guess that the answer is "yes".  The way matrix multiplication is normally done in computer graphics is to multiply new matrices on the object side of the model matrix (look into OpenGL to see how this works in practice).

Comment: but if I try RotationMatrix*model, how do I apply that logic to a point, which is only one vector and not three vectors(as a matrix is)? --and I am using row vectors :) and the function MultiplyByMatrix accepts either one vector, and multiplies it by the local matrix, but is also overloaded to accept four vectors, one being the vector to multiply, the other 3 being the matrix to multiply by. PointsPlusMatrix just multiplies all the points, normals, etc by the matrix given to the function.

Comment: You do realize that you can multiply two matrices together to get another matrix, right?  Since there will usually be lots of points in your model that need transforming in exactly the same way, you want to combine all your transforms together, so that you only need to transform each point once.  (That is what the first code section of my answer is demonstrating.)

Comment: Also: matrix and vector multiplication is associative, so that (if `A` and `B` are matrices and `r` is a row vector), `(r*A)*B == r*(A*B)`.

Comment: Finally, even if you don't want to do that:  if you want to rotate your object in object space, the obvious thing to do is to multiply it by a rotation matrix *before* doing all the other transformations you want to do.

Comment: Yes, I know two matrices can be multiplied together, and I know the multiplications are associative for vector and matrix multiplication, the problem is, since you say what needs to be done is to multiply the rotation matrix by the model, I don't have a function for that, but do you mean instead of: (XMatrix * vector.x) + (YMatrix * vector.y) + (ZMatrix * vector.z) to use (vector.x * XMatrix) + (vector.y * YMatrix) + (vector.z * ZMatrix), but it would still have the same results? how exactly do you do vector*matrix instead of matrix*vector

Comment: No, I mean:  first, multiply each point `p` in object space by your object rotation `Robj` to get a new point `q= p * Robj`.  Then, do whatever transformations you would have done on `p`, but instead do them on `q`.

Comment: Or, equivalently:  combine your matrix `Robj` with the transformation `T` that you would have done on `p` by computing the matrix `RandT= Robj * T`, and using `RandT` instead of `T`.

Comment: In other words:  instead of doing `vector*matrix`, do `vector*rotmatrix*matrix`.  You can do it as `(vector*rotmatrix)*matrix`, or you can do it as `vector*(rotmatrix*matrix)`, but that's how you rotate your object points in object space.

Comment: If things are still not clear, my best advice is that you probably need to work on your matrix math some more.  Unfortunately, this is not a good forum for that kind of thing.

Comment: it is clear, but that wont work :(, if you multiply the point by the object rotation, (try it) you just end up with excessive rotation, because the multiplication on the point acts on the point as it is, not as it was, this is back to my original problem, I have to get rid of the excessive rotation, as I don't want to have to store in the RAM the entire mesh, in original coordinates :(, there has to be some way to "un"rotate a point by its current matrix, so that I can multiply it by the object oriented rotation. that was my attempt at using the inverse. there must be a simpler way...

Comment: John what you do is you split your world into more a complex hierarchy. You store objects for certain calumniation advantage in different spaces. So what you do for each object one space, a relation to world space and each one. Your problem is that your prematurely optimizing WITH wrong assumptions. The matrix operation is really really fast, you can do it on the fly. Besides accumulation transformation on the individual vertices is really a bad idea the solution will drift over time. Its possible to unrotate same thing its just not done because of the stability issue. This is the easy way.