# C# Matrix3D - what is the "_matrix" member?

Tags: c#, wpf, matrix, 3d

I'm looking for some example code to do 3D rotations using C#/WPF's Matrix3D structure.
On the Stack Overflow question [Rotation Matrix given angle and point in X,Y,Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188876/rotation-matrix-given-angle-and-point-in-x-y-z), second answer by Jordan Arron I thought I found just what I was looking for except that references to the _matrix member, e.g.,

```
var matrix = new Matrix3D();
matrix._matrix[1, 1] = Math.Cos(radians);
```

... fail on the second line with "*System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Matrix3D' does not contain a definition for matrix*"  (notice that it says "matrix", not "_matrix" - why?)

I see this same syntax:  matrix._matrix[j,k] used in other examples on the web, too, e.g., https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/building-a-simple-3d-engine-with-silverlight/
... but I don't see a _matrix member in the structure definition (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.matrix3d.aspx)

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be mixing up two Matrix3D classes in separate namespaces:
System.Windows.Media.Media3D and com.bodurov.LinesIn3D.Matrix3D

**System.Windows.Media.Media3D** does not contain the member _matrix.

See the source code here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.matrix3d(v=vs.90).aspx

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.matrix3d.aspx

However....

**com.bodurov.LinesIn3D.Matrix3D** DOES contain the member _matrix

See the source code here: https://vectorvisualizer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#com.bodurov.LinesIn3D/Matrix3D.cs

Documentation: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/building-a-simple-3d-engine-with-silverlight/

Comment: In the answer I referenced in the original link the poster who answered **specifically** referenced (linked to) the MSDN's version of Matrix3D, which is why I was confused.  Thanks for clearing this up.    BTW, do you know any good code examples of using the MSDN's Matrix3D to do rotations?