# c# - Rotating Points About Axis

Tags: c#, rotation

I currently have code that will generate segment points and at each segment point will generate some points within a short cylinder around the point (in 3D, the segments positions all have a z value of 0.0F (however I'd like to have varying z-values that are in a line - i.e. it's still in a line, but in the line z = 3x for example), but the x, and y are randomised). However currently all the points generated are in a cylinder that is facing upwards, I want to be able to rotate the points such that the cylinder they are 'generated' in is facing in the direction between the two segments. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRiLE.png) an image of what it should look like vs. what it currently looks like

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188876/rotation-matrix-given-angle-and-point-in-x-y-z) similar question about rotating points around an axis; I took the answer and used that code for my RotatePoints() function but it doesn't seem to work correctly and I'm not sure why. Below is my psuedo code, what would I need to do get this function working correctly? Is there a better way to do this? The points just need to be generated within a rotated cylinder so would a completely different method be more efficient and easier?

All I have is the location of each segment and each point stored as a Vector3 {x,y,z} in local space.

Psuedo-Code

```
double radius;
// Generates the positions where the points will be generated around
// These are just the x,y,z positions of the object in world space
Vector3[] segmentLocations = GenerateSegmentPositions(numSegments);

for (int i = 0; i < numSegments; i++) {
    // Generates points in a cylinder facing up the +ve y-axis
    // This works fine        
    Vector3[][] pointsAroundSegment = GeneratePoints(segmentLocations[i], radius);

    if (i != numSegments - 1 && i > 0) {
        // Generate a normalise direction vector for the new direction
        Vector3 newDir = Vector3.Normalise(segmentLocations[i + 1] - segmentLocations[i]);
        double theta = Vector3.AngleBetween(newDir - Vector3.Normalise(segmentLocations[i] - segmentLocations[i - 1]));
        // Rotates points (this currently rotates the points so they 'should' be facing the new direction, I haven't yet modified this to face the halfway point)
        // This doesn't work
        pointsAroundSegment = RotatePoints(pointsAroundSegment, newDir, theta/2);
    } else if (i == numSegments - 1) {
        // Generate final point
        // This works fine
        pointsAboutSegment = GenerateFinalPoint(segmentLocations[i]);
    }
}

// This is the actual rotation function
// RotatePoints() effectively just calls this for each point in the array
public static double[] Rotate(double x, double y, double z, double u, double v, double w, double theta) {
    double[] c = new double[3];
    c [0] = u * (u * x + v * y + w * z) * (1 - Math.Cos (theta)) + x * Math.Cos (theta) + (-w * y + v * z) * Math.Sin (theta);
    c [1] = v * (u * x + v * y + w * z) * (1 - Math.Cos (theta)) + y * Math.Cos (theta) + (w * x - u * z) * Math.Sin (theta);
    c [2] = w * (u * x + v * y + w * z) * (1 - Math.Cos (theta)) + z * Math.Cos (theta) + (-v * x + u * y) * Math.Sin (theta);

    return c;
}
```

Comment: I think that equation rotates the points around the segment about the origin, and I could be wrong, but I think you want to be rotating about your current segment location. Try the simplified formula [f(x,y,z,a,b,c,u,v,w,θ)](https://sites.google.com/site/glennmurray/Home/rotation-matrices-and-formulas/rotation-about-an-arbitrary-axis-in-3-dimensions), with (a,b,c) being your current segment location.

Comment: You're right. That simplified formula works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer courtesy of Poosh;

To rotate the point (x,y,z) about the line through (a,b,c) with the normalised (u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 1) direction vector  by the angle theta use the following function:

```
public static double[] Rotate(double x, double y, double z, double a, double b, double c, double nu, double nv, double nw, double theta) {
    double[] rP = new double[3];

    rP [0] = (a * (nv * nv + nw * nw) - nu * (b * nv + c * nw - nu * x - nv * y - nw * z)) * (1 - Math.Cos (theta)) + x * Math.Cos (theta) + (-c * nv + b * nw - nw * y + nv * z) * Math.Sin (theta);
    rP [1] = (b * (nu * nu + nw * nw) - nv * (a * nu + c * nw - nu * x - nv * y - nw * z)) * (1 - Math.Cos (theta)) + y * Math.Cos (theta) + (c * nu - a * nw + nw * x - nu * z) * Math.Sin (theta);
    rP [2] = (c * (nu * nu + nv * nv) - nw * (a * nu + b * nv - nu * x - nv * y - nw * z)) * (1 - Math.Cos (theta)) + z * Math.Cos (theta) + (-b * nu + a * nv - nv * x + nu * y) * Math.Sin (theta);

    return rP;
}
```