# 4x4 3D Matrix Manipulation

Tags: c#, object, matrix, 3d

I am currently working on a game project with C# and I am working on moving a camera in 3D space. I have a 4x4 global world matrix. I understand this matrix handles the translation and rotation of the object in space. I currently know that the 3rd row handles the position of the object so I am able to move the camera along the xyz plane. However I want to perform rotate the camera along both the local axis and global axis. referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982418/how-to-represent-a-4x4-matrix-rotation) post I have an idea how to rotate the camera. I would however like to have a clearer understanding of the matrix and what the various rows and columns represent so far as translation and rotation are concerned. I also want to know if the 4x4 matrix contains information regarding both local and global position of the camera. Meaning will i be able to manipulate the matrix to rotate the camera about an external axis or point ? Just how much can I do to the camera given this matrix

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the real (1) question, 3D maths is a lot more complex than you think.

Ignoring quaternions for now, a matrix can be thought of in terms of:-

```
Rx Ry Rz 0
Ux Uy Uz 0
Ax Ay Az 0
Px Py Pz 1
```

or it might be the transpose of the above, it depends on how you set up the system, but in the end it really makes little difference and depends a lot on your hardware. R is the Right axis, U is the Up axis, A is the At axis and P is the position. The x, y, and z suffix if the component of each vector. This is quite easy to visualise: think of a set of orthognal unit vectors for the first three to define the rotation and the last is where the matrix is in the world and that is the above matrix.

Once you've got your head around the above, moving it should be fairly easy to see. Rotating it however, is a lot more complex. Looking at something is easy:

```
 A = |target pos - camera pos| (pos is bottom row here)
```

and then R and U are cross products of A and a global axis pointing in the correct direction.

Matrices can be rotated about an arbitary axis (the local and global axes you mention fall into this) but the maths is very complex (too complex for this answer).

This site goes into more detail: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) There are a few standard matrix operations listed here. You could also check out the Wolfram site for a more in depth discussion and there are certainly good resources online if you look.

Matrices can be multiplied together, the result is effectively the combination of the actions each matrix does on its own. So you could have one matrix as a general movement (with unit, axis aligned vectors for the direction parts) and another matrix could be a rotation matrix at (0,0,0). The product of these two would then be a movement and rotation matrix. This is how object hierachies work and object placement in the world work. Also, it's used in animation too.

The API you're using should provide an API to rotate matrices about arbitary axis, but its useful to have an idea of what's going on.

Once you've got your head around all that, you could look at quaternions. Just remember that there's nothing a you can do with a quaternion that you can't do using matrices.

(1) As far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

In 3d graphics rotation is represented rather by quaternion than matrix. There is a set of functions to operate quaternions.

You can [perform rotation along any axis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205415(v=vs.85).aspx) you want with quaternions. You can easily combine and even (wich is hardly ever possible to matrices) interpolate quaternions.

Quaternions can be converted to a matrix, that is the way how any rotation matrix can be produced.
If you want to apply rotation to object or combine rotation with another transformation such as translation or scaling, you should convert the quaternion to a matrix first.

DirectX SDK is a great source of information about matrices and quaternions, no matter wich API you actually use - the math is uniform across all 3d APIs.

On your question about matrix row/column meaning: matrix can represent quite complex transformation, including scaling or rotation across point other than the geometry center of the object. So you should not think of the matrix in that manner, you should imagine a complex matrix as a multiplication of simple matrices instead.

Comment: Ignore this about quaternions. If you're just starting out this is complex, and most hardware uses matricies anyway. It has it's place (animation for one), but not here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question is what operations to perfom in order to do such rotations about specific axis. @skizz What do I do to the current matrix of the object for example to rotate it about the origin perhaps. Are there standard matrix operations to achieve this ?

Comment: [D3DXMatrixRotationAxis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205357(v=vs.85).aspx) or [glRotatef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368577(v=vs.85).aspx) is probably what you are looking for.